# SPServices loop through multiple listNames

Tags: sharepoint, spservices

I'm using SPServices to get Sharepoint (2010) list items

```
function GetListItemData() {
  var container = $("#container");
  $(container).html("");
  var datarows = [];
  // get list data
  $().SPServices({
    webUrl: "https://",
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: myList, // Using GUID should work across multisite apps
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Body' /><FieldRef Name='PublishingPageImage' /><FieldRef Name='PublishingImageCaption' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function(xData, Status){
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){
        var x={
          name: myList,
          title: $(this).attr("ows_Title"),
          image: $(this).attr("ows_PublishingPageImage"),
          caption: $(this).attr("ows_PublishingImageCaption"),
          body: $(this).attr("ows_Body")
        };
        datarows.push(x);
      });
    }
  });
```

I'm updating content now by data- attr on links of various lists and running the function again.

Any lead on the proper/best way to loop through all the lists to create a dashboard of all of them?

Any direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Lists.GetListCollection Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistcollection.aspx) returns list information for all lists in the site.

**SPServices example**

```
function getListCollection(completeFn)
{ 
    $().SPServices({ 
        operation: "GetListCollection", 
        completefunc: function( xData, Status ) {
            var lists = [];
            $( xData.responseXML ).find("Lists > List").each(function(i,el) {
                var listJson = listXml2Json(el.outerHTML);
                lists.push(listJson);
            });
            completeFn(lists);
        } 
    });
}



function listXml2Json(value)
{ 
    var jsonObject = {};
    var schemaXml = $.parseXML(value);
    $(schemaXml).find('List').each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attr){
           jsonObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
      });
    });
    return jsonObject;
}    


//print lists title
getListCollection(
   function(lists){
       lists.forEach(function(list){
           console.log(list.Title); 
       });
   });
```

Comment: Vadim, thanks a lot for pointing this out. getListCollection works to return all the title, UID and number of list items within each, but I'm unclear on how to access the list items within each collection. Any thoughts?

With this solution, it seems like I'll still need to utilize getlistitems in addition to pull the collection list items. Any idea what I'm missing? 

Again thanks for the help!

Comment: As far as I know there is no such operation that returns list collection with item collection. From another hand it would be very expensive from performance perspective to return all lists with items. Having said that you could consider the following options 1) perform multiple requests to return list collection and after that items per list  2) consider CSOM API instead of SharePoint Web Services since it supports request batching

Comment: @VadimGremyachev , can you pls help. I want to retrieve the task listitems from all the subsites of my sitecollection and to be shown on the landing page. Can you pls suggest the right approach. Can i use spservices  withina  content editor web part and use the above code?